# Swagger Codegen, Maven Plugin: Restrict Server Generation

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-codegen

I want to generate JAX-RS server stubs for my API using the swagger-codegen maven plugin, but I want to use my own service implementation class, instead of the one generated. Is there way to generate everything except this class? For my API, the tool generates four api classes: ProfilesApi,ProfilesApiService, ProfilesApiServiceFactory and ProfilesApiServiceImpl.

My current maven configuration:

```
                     <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>src/main/resources/Profile.json</inputSpec>
                         <language>jaxrs</language>
                        <configOptions>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                        </configOptions>
                        <models>Profile,PageInformation,ProfileResult</models>
                        <modelPackage>com.myApp.profile-api-model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>com.myApp.profile-api-webapp</apiPackage>
                        <library>jersey2</library>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <!-- change default client library (here until plugin 2.1.5). Doesn't seem to work! -->
                            <library>jersey2</library>
                            <!-- generate all models -->
                            <models></models>
                            <!-- generate all APIs -->
                            <apis></apis>
                            <!-- generate just the supporting files that are Java source code (not project build files) -->
                            <supportingFiles>ApiException.java,ApiOriginFilter.java,ApiResponseMessage.java,JacksonJsonProvider.java,LocalDateProvider.java,LocalDateTimeProvider.java,NotFoundException.java,StringUtil.java,web.xml,ProfilesApi.java,ProfilesApiService.java,ProfilesApiServiceFactory.java</supportingFiles>
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be wise to create your own template instead of modifying the default behavior of the generator.

Comment: @fehguy Defining my own custom generator and templates seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

The proper way to do this is via two configuration options, `<generateSupportingFiles>` in the configuration and `<interfaceOnly>` in the `<configOptions>`. The `<generateSupportingFiles>` does not generate the executable entry point, `pom.xml` etc., while the `<interfaceOnly>` flag does not generate the implementation of the service, only the interface. This way you can have your own executable class doing other stuff, your own `pom.xml` and your own service implementation, and you can regenerate the API and the Model as many times as you want using the `mvn clean package`.

I am not sure if the Jersey templates check for `<interfaceOnly`, but the Spring Boot and CXF JAX-RS templates do.

In your maven `pom.xml`, your `<configuration>` inside the build plugin of the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` would need to look like this:

```
<generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
<configOptions>
    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
...
</configOptions>
```

Unfortunately these configuration options are not very well documented, you have to do a lot of research and stumble upon them on some github issue.

Comment: Didn't work for me. This helped: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4444#issuecomment-270204233: `**/*Impl.java` in `.swagger-codegen-ignore`

Comment: @stef77 You shouldn't need to do that... maybe you should describe in more detail what 'didn't work for you'. The approach you used is flawed (see below).

Comment: With no combination of the configuration properties I could prevent that default implementation classes are generated.

Comment: Happens only with `<language>jaxrs-jersey</language>`. Switched to jaxrs-spec where there's no implementation classes generated.

Comment: OK, must be a bug in the generation templates of jaxrs-jersey.

Answer (score -1):

There are two steps to the solution here.

1. Add **/*Controller.java or **/*Impl.java to .swagger-codegen-ignore file ( in target/generated-sources). Depending on the language used the default implementation is provided in a *Controller.java or *Impl.java file. Once the default implementation is excluded from generation, you can implement the generated interfaces in your own class. The code in your own class will not get refreshed on mvn clean.
2. swagger-codegen-ignore file itself is an auto-generated file hence whatever you add in step 1 gets refreshed when you do a mvn clean. To avoid this add the below plugin to your pom:

   ```
   <plugin>                
   <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.1</version>
   <configuration>
   <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
   <filesets>
   <fileset>
   <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
   <excludes>
   <exclude>generated-sources/.swagger-codegen-ignore</exclude>
   </excludes>
   </fileset>
   </filesets>
   </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

Comment: Won't the files in generated-sources get deleted the moment you do `mvn clean`? And how is this supposed to work between multiple developers? Generated sources aren't supposed to be committed to source control.

Answer (score -2):

You must use the codegen ignore file to prevent the implementation  classes generation